# Perl how to get values from bless object request data

Tags: perl, xml-rpc, bless

I am using RPC::XML and parsing request xml using below code and request xml.

```
use RPC::XML::ParserFactory 'XML::Parser';
my $P = RPC::XML::ParserFactory->new();
my $parse_data = $P->parse($xml_data); 
print Dumper($parse_data);
```

**Request xml:**

```
<methodCall>
<methodName>get_topic</methodName>
<params>
<param>
<value>
<string>163397</string>
</value>
</param>
<param>
<value>
<i4>0</i4>
</value>
</param>
<param>
<value>
<i4>19</i4>
</value>
</param>
<param>
<value>
<string>ANN</string>
</value>
</param>
</params>
</methodCall>
```

I have get object data:

```
bless( {
'name' => 'get_topic',
'args' => [
            bless( do{\\(my $o = '163397')}, 'RPC::XML::string' ),
            bless( do{\\(my $o = '0')}, 'RPC::XML::i4' ),
            bless( do{\\(my $o = '19')}, 'RPC::XML::i4' ),
            bless( do{\\(my $o = 'ANN')}, 'RPC::XML::string' )
          ]
}, 'RPC::XML::request' );
```

After I have done `print Dumper($parse_data->args);` and get below args object data:

bless( {

```
$VAR1 = [
         bless( do{\\(my $o = '163397')}, 'RPC::XML::string' ),
         bless( do{\\(my $o = '0')}, 'RPC::XML::i4' ),
         bless( do{\\(my $o = '19')}, 'RPC::XML::i4' ),
         bless( do{\\(my $o = 'ANN')}, 'RPC::XML::string' )
      ];
```

Now how to get values from this args object data? please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but according to [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~rjray/RPC-XML-0.78/lib/RPC/XML.pm) this should work:

```
my $args = $parse_data->args;
for my $arg (@$args) {
   print $arg->type, ": ", $arg->value, "\n";
}
```

In particular read the [Message Classes](http://search.cpan.org/~rjray/RPC-XML-0.78/lib/RPC/XML.pm#Message_Classes) documentation which explains the methods of `RPC::XML::request` and [Data Classes](http://search.cpan.org/~rjray/RPC-XML-0.78/lib/RPC/XML.pm#Data_Classes) which explains `RPC::XML::string` and friends.